# SEO Sitemap for Subdomain

Tags: seo, sitemap, yahoo

Basically i have a site call (e.g. domain.com), and i allow my customers to host their site on my domain (e.g. theirsite.domain.com)

I have a sitemap for domain.com, but have no linkage to theirsite.domain.com, as a result, these subdomain(s) cannot be found on google.

I have considered generating the site map dynimcally, but it wouldn't be ideal, as there might have 100,000 sites on my domain, causing huge resource consumption and slow generating time.

Is there any ideal way to let the search engine crawl my domain.com, as well as my customer sites (xx.domain.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Webmasters Tools

[Site Verification and Sitemap generation](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=100450)